# ssh connection shows control keys as ^P or ^A

Tags: ssh, readline, sungridengine

When I press ctrl-p it is displayed as `^P` instead of recalling previous input line. Same goes for all the other readline control keys like ctrl-a (start of line). This happens with all the tools I use that have readline functionality built-in. Running the tools without ssh, works fine.

```
ssh server1 dc_shell     // BAD  ctrl-p is displayed as ^P
dc_shell                 // OK   ctrl-p recalls last line
ssh server1              // OK! I get a bash shell where ctrl-p recalls last line
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-t` ssh option (force pseudo-terminal allocation):

```
ssh server1 -t dc_shell
```

or add `RequestTTY=yes` to `~/.ssh/config`